# How to Unit Test a Protected Method with database connection inside a public method in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Child : Parent
{

private int _eventTypeId;
 public override Dictionary<string, dynamic> Execute(IDynamicDatabaseConnection dbConn, IDbTransaction dbTrans)
        {
_eventTypeId = GetEventType(dbConn, dbTrans);
}
}
```

```
public abstract class Parent : ParentInterface
    {
protected int GetEventType(IDynamicDatabaseConnection dbConn, IDbTransaction dbTrans) => GetItemId("EventType", "User Initiated", dbConn, dbTrans);

 protected int GetItemId(string param1, string param2, IDynamicDatabaseConnection dbConn, IDbTransaction dbTrans) =>
            dbConn.Query<int>(
                $@"myQuery",
                dbTrans).FirstOrDefault();


public abstract Dictionary<string, dynamic> Execute(IDynamicDatabaseConnection dbConn, IDbTransaction dbTrans);
}
```

```
    public interface ParentInterface
    {
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> Execute(IDynamicDatabaseConnection dbConn, IDbTransaction dbTrans);
    }
```

How should I be mocking the `GetEventType` method from my child class?

I use mocking in the following way.

```
            var connMock = A.Fake<IDynamicDatabaseConnection>();
            var transMock = A.Fake<IDbTransaction>();
            A.CallTo(() => connMock.BeginTransaction()).Returns(transMock);
A.CallTo(() => dbConnMock.Query<string>(null, null, null, A<bool>._, null, null)).WithAnyArguments().Returns(new List<string>() { "AfterSaveSPName" });
```

Update:
Adding the Child Class Test Method which I am testing.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Initiate_Intake_Should_Insert_FormMode_Initiate()
        {
            // Arrange
            Dictionary<string, dynamic> childParameters = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
            {
                 {Key, -1}
            };
            var dynamicAssembly = A.Fake<IDynamicAssembly>();
            var connMock = A.Fake<IDynamicDatabaseConnection>();
            var transMock = A.Fake<IDbTransaction>();
            var fakeInitiateIntake = A.Fake<InitiateBase>(options => options.Implements<IInitiateBase>());
            
A.CallTo(() => connMock.BeginTransaction()).Returns(transMock);
            A.CallTo(fakeInitiateIntake).Where(call => call.Method.Name == "GetEventType")
                .WithReturnType<int>()
                .Returns(197);

            // Act
            var child = new Child(childParameters, dynamicAssembly);
            child.Execute(connMock, transMock);

            // Assert
            initiateParameters["Key"].Equals(1234);
        }
```

Comment: You could create a [TestClass] like =>  ChildTestClass : Parent  ... inside your test. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416223/unit-testing-c-sharp-protected-methods

Comment: "I use mocking in the following way."  Ok, but what happens when you tried that approach? Did you get an error?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yes, It didn't mock `GetEventType` the way I hoped.

Comment: @Mate But, the comments on the accepted answer tell that it's not the right way. I am hoping to find the right way to mock this.

Comment: You didn't specify `GetEventType` at all in your mocking code.  Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @KirkWoll Yeah, how should I do that is the main question. That method is protected in the Parent class.

Comment: Right, but if the problem is simply that you can't access it if it's protected, it would really help for you to show the code which _tried_ to reference the protected method (even if it won't compile), and then we could (hopefully) come up with solutions that addressed that.

Comment: @tRuEsAtM  Think it as a stub.  Maybe that comments apply to another scenario.  How do the test / fwk tools work under the hood?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601730/should-private-protected-methods-be-under-unit-test

Comment: This cannot be done with constrained isolating frameworks such as Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy. This is possible with the help of unconstrained frameworks such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect

Comment: @Mate I have updated the question with the method I am trying to test.

Comment: @KirkWoll I have updated the question with the method I am trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said, but I'm assuming you're trying to test `Child`.

First, note that FakeItEasy will not be able to intercept calls to
`GetEventType`
[unless the method is virtual or abstract](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/#what-members-can-be-overridden).
If you're able to make that change, you can follow the instructions at
[Specifying a call to any method or property](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-any-method-or-property),
which shows an example using a protected method's name to identify it. You'll
end up with something like this:

```cs
A.CallTo(fakeChild).Where(call => call.Method.Name == "GetEventType")
                   .WithReturnType<int>()
                   .Returns(197);
```

Comment: What is `fakeChild`? Is it an object of Child class? You are right I want to test the Child class.

Comment: I have updated the question with the method I am trying to test.

Comment: `fakeChild` was to have been a fake `Child`. You said you wanted to mock "the `GetEventType` method from [the] child class", so it sounded like you needed a fake Child. If that's true, I think you make a fake Child and use something like my answer. With your update, I don't know really how to help you. We don't know what `InitiateBase` is, nor how it's connected to `Child`. You fake it, but then never supply `fakeInitiateIntake` to `Child`. And then `initiateParameters` shows up at the end, unconnected to anything.