# Pass parameters to PrivateObject method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private-methods

I am trying to unit test private method.
I saw example below on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp)

```
Class target = new Class();
PrivateObject obj = new PrivateObject(target);
var retVal = obj.Invoke("PrivateMethod");
Assert.AreEqual(retVal);
```

My private method has 2 ref params.
How to pass them?

Comment: Have you looked at the overloads for [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243741.aspx)?  Do none of them work for you?

Comment: try -> `obj.Invoke("PrivateMethod",ref yourparmarray);`

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I have looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx but not sure how to use. I am missing example.

Comment: @TomTom You can not be sure what I did. Surely I did same search around and did not find anything helpful.

Comment: @eomeroff If you did some "search around" then it is good to include your findings in the question, to explain what exactly don't you understand from the documentation.

Comment: Just as an aside, I and many others would suggest not unit testing private methods directly. By all means ensure that all logic paths are covered, but if you *can't* reach it from a public method, you can be sure that line of logic is dead code.

Comment: @BartoszKP You must admit that it is going too far. People who try to demystify MSDN while trying to solve the problem are true heroes.

Comment: @eomeroff What is going too far? Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you pass the argument array, then any `ref` parameters will be populated in place:

```
bool p1 = true; // can be others values
bool p2 = false; // can be others values
object[] args = new object[2] { p1, p2 };
var retval = obj.Invoke("PrivateMethod", args);

p1 = (bool)args[0];
p2 = (bool)args[1];
```

Comment: My parameters are bool type.

Comment: What if parameter types are mixed, not all same type?

Answer (score 3):

First create an object array of your parameters.  the array should then contain the new references:

```
Class target = new Class();
PrivateObject obj = new PrivateObject(target);
object[] args = new object[] {arg1, arg2};
var retVal = obj.Invoke("PrivateMethodWithArgs", args);
Assert.AreEqual(retVal);

Debug.WriteLine(args[0]);
Debug.WriteLine(args[1]);
```

Comment: you don't pass `args` to `Invoke` :-)

Comment: @Grundy missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
object [] myarray=new object[]{param1,param2};
var retVal = obj.Invoke("PrivateMethod",ref myarray);
```

Comment: This is not compiling.

Comment: remove the ref from myarray