# How to write nunit test case for internal type class having protected methods?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

How to write Nunit test case for a class of internal type having protected methods.
Should i use inheritance for this?
Following is the class, for which i am trying to write test case:-

```
internal class CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestTanslator
{
    protected override CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestType BusinessToService(IEntityTranslatorService service, BuyerAbuseRequest value)
    {
        //code
    }
 }
```

Please, suggest me how to write test case for this class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing private methods in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, how to call internal class in the test case?

Comment: The answer suggests you can only test public API.  It also suggests if a component inside of a class can be independently tested, it might also imply the class can be split up into several associated classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Test-Specific subclass](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test-Specific%20Subclass.html) if you want to test protected methods explicitely.

The simpliest example is below:

```
internal class CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestTanslatorTSS : CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestTanslator
{
    public CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestType ExposeBusinessToService(IEntityTranslatorService service, BuyerAbuseRequest value) 
    {
        return BusinessToServic(service, value);
    }
}
```

And in you tests you will be able to call protected methods through the public ones in a Test-Specific subclass.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SubclassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var sut = new CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestTanslatorTSS();

        //arrange your system under test here
        //...

        var result = sut.ExposeBusinessToService(service, value);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
    }
}
```

The other option is to use reflection:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ReflectionTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var sut = new CSGetBuyerAbuseReportsRequestTanslator();

        //arrange your system under test here
        //...

        var result = sut.GetType()
                        .GetMethod("BusinessToService", BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                        .Invoke(result, new [] {service, value});

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
    }
}
```

However you should consider splitting your class if you can't test through its public interfaces.

Your class is internal in the example, if you have tests in a separate assembly you should use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to be able to access it from the tests assembly.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you have a separate assembly that contains unit tests. If so, you can add a line to the AssemblyInfo.cs file of the assembly being tested similar to the following (substitute your unit test assembly's name for `AssemblyB`):

`[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]`

This will allow your unit test assembly to access the `internal` class(es) contained in the assembly you are testing. See [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx), which states the following regarding the use of `InternalsVisibleTo`:

> This is especially convenient...when test code runs in a separate assembly but requires access to members in the assembly being tested that are marked as **Friend** (Visual Basic) or **internal**  (C#).