# unit test for private static method in non-static class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

how to write unit test for private static method in c#? Is that good to have private static method?

```
private static <someReturnType> SomeMethodName(SomeParameters){}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing private methods in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp)

Comment: No, it's not. Regardless of the advisability of testing private methods (I tend to believe that they should be tested), the process used to test an object's methods does not work for static methods.

Comment: Would love an actual answer to this question. It's strange the approach for testing private members doesn't work for static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is don't test the implementation details of your class, test its behaviour or interactions. The fact that the method is static is irrelevant.

You unit test should validate that given some conditions, calling a public method results in some expected response or expected interaction with dependencies. **How** that response is generated or how the interactions happen in the class under test are not really important, what's important is the externally verifiable behaviour.