# C# 7 how to unit test local functions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-7.0

I've been looking at some articles about local functions, and the one sentence states:

> Local functions are defined within a method and aren't available outside of it

So given the below code example is there any way to unit test the `square` method?

```
int SumAndSquare(int x, int y)
{
    var sum = x + y;
    return square(sum);

    int square(int z)
    {
        return z * z;
    }
}
```

Comment: By unit testing `SumAndSquare`. That's the unit (or not in this case, as it's private, but it would be if it was public).

Comment: In the same way you unit test private methods: you don't. You unit test the public part of your class.

Comment: You can only test the outcome of the SumAndSquare-Method. Not the local function.

Comment: @xanatos it's possible to test private methods using the PrivateObject Class, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp) question. I'm interested in knowing if a solution exists for testing local funcations

Comment: @AdamT But I support the accepted response of [Keith Nicholas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122724/613130): *Yes, don't Test private methods.... The idea of a unit test is to test the unit by its public 'API'.* . I'm not saying that it isn't possible to execute private methods... I use reflection even to heat the milk in the morning :-)

Comment: Check the duplicate even if it is about F#. F# supports nested functions from day 1. They are extremely useful but not a replacement for private methods. For example, if a nested function is used only by its parent, why would you need to test it separately? If it's so complicated that it needs testing, you are probably doing it wrong

Comment: I don't see that the F# question is a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general you can't in a maintainable way for non-trivial local functions (reason explained in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715550/c-sharp-7-how-to-unit-testing-local-functions/42715858#comment72552228_42715858) to this response). A local function that uses variables of the method where it is defined (so a non-trivial one, ones that don't use local variables could be private methods) has a special parameter containing these variables. You can't easily recreate this parameter → you can't call it.

It can be easily seen in [TryRoslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGPAbxg5d05kmRgBiAeyEAKAJR4erKT058YRGAF4YAVhzc5HAE6pkwHRBgA3GiWCohAMwBC+CyAAaoteM2ztCsxat2HoC4KAB6SWtoy4dqcegZGijAA1DDBmtEwAL6emXgZQA=) (how much I love TryRoslyn! I use it very often )

```
int Foo()
{
    int b = 5;
    return valueofBplusX(5);

    int valueofBplusX(int x)
    {
        return b + x;
    }
}
```

is translated in something like:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
private struct <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int b;
}

private int Foo()
{
    C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = default(C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0);
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.b = 5;
    return C.<Foo>g__valueofBplusX0_0(5, ref <>c__DisplayClass0_);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
internal static int <Foo>g__valueofBplusX0_0(int x, ref C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 ptr)
{
    return ptr.b + x;
}
```

You see the `<>c__DisplayClass0_0` that contains the `b` local variable, and the `<Foo>g__valueofBplusX0_0` that receives as the second argument a `ref C.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 ptr`?

On top of this, I'll add a quote of [Keith Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122724/613130): *Yes, don't Test private methods.... The idea of a unit test is to test the unit by its public 'API'.*

Comment: I'm not saying you should, but you still _can_ do this, by constructing an instance of the display class using reflection as well.

Comment: @caesay It isn't maintainable (I was waiting for this question )... The name of the local variables of a function aren't part of its "external interface"... They can be changed/refactored at the whim of a programmer, and this will break your unit testing (because your unit test will break on filling the `<>c__DisplayClass0_0`).

Comment: TryRoslyn gives a great insight into whats actually happening, I can see how hard it would be to maintain unit tests on local methods.