# Unit Test the a string that is used to pass to another function using XUnit and NSubstitute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, nsubstitute

So I have a function like this that will call other function and pass in a string that will be returned based on different condition. They will always use a normal string, however if certain conditions are met then the special string will be used to passed in to the other function instead.

```
public async Task Func(context)
{
    var stringToBeUsed  = GetNormalString(context);

    if (FirstConditionFulfilled(context) && 
        (SecondConditionFulfilled(context))
    {
        stringToBeUsed  = GetSpecialString(context);
    }

    await DoSthElse(context, stringToBeUsed );
}
```

This is the get normal string function

```
private string GetNormalString(context)
        => context.HttpContext.DoSthToGetNormalString().ToString();
```

And this is the get special string function

```
private string GetSpecialString(context)
        => context.HttpContext.DoSthToGetSpecialString().ToString;
```

I wonder how should I set up the unit test to see if certain conditions are met, the stringToBeUsed will be the special string, otherwise, will be the normal string?

Comment: You can substitute only virtual methods.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov can you elaborate more on that please? Cause virtual methods are about inheritance and I don't have any inheritance implementation in my examples.

Answer (score 2):

Your Function does two things:

1. get the special string and then
2. do something with it.

That makes it hard to test. Why dont you put the getting of the string in a new function and now each function only does one thing that you can test easier:

```
public string GetTheRightString(context){ //new function you can easily test
    var stringToBeUsed  = GetNormalString(context);
    if (FirstConditionFulfilled(context) && 
        (SecondConditionFulfilled(context))
    {
        stringToBeUsed  = GetSpecialString(context);
    }

    return stringTobeUsed;
}

public async Task Func(context)
{
    var stringToBeUsed  = GetTheRightString(context);
    await DoSthElse(context, stringToBeUsed );
}
```

But you probably dont want to make that method public. If you keep it private and you want to test it (which is a topic some people are very dogmatic about that you should never do that. I disagree) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122708/unit-testing-private-methods-in-c-sharp). Or you put the method in a new class and make that public/internal. There is no right or wrong here in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, breaking the function into 2 smaller functions seems to be the right approach. However, I would prefer not to have the function GetTheRightString be public since no other class would need to use it so I do not want to expose its detail.

Comment: @Noelia i added some info. Maybe that helps you how to go from there

Comment: By the way @HrkBrkkl, I was wondering if the normal string use context.HttpContext.Request.Query[string].ToString(); and context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(); how can I unit test it? I consider using  httpContextMock.Setup(x => x.Request.Query().Returns(normalString); And what should I Assert it equals to?